# How to reset WebSphere wasadmin password

Tags: passwords, websphere, admin, reset, maximo

I have tried following this tutorial but the new password doesn't take effect after security is enabled again, still have to use old password to login as wasadmin:
http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2014/03/27/reset-websphere-admin-console-password/

I even tried the guide from IBM:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21392427

But I'm lost at this step: 
_Navigate via command prompt to /ConfigEngine

Because in my WebSphere it doesn't have this ConfigEngine folder in order the run the rest of the commands.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: This is WebSphere 7 for Maximo 7.5

Comment: It may not be under \WebSphere\AppServer\ConfigEngine but should be under  the following path 
\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\cw_profile\ConfigEngine .  There should be a ConfigEngine folder up to your installation type. 

  
Another suggestion would be for  you, if you're are working on a local server, just create a new server with a new username and password in order for you to continue your work.  Otherwise, I would suggest you to create a new user via the admin console .

Comment: A few comments: 1. `ConfigEngine` is used by WebSphere Portal, not Application Server. 2. You did not specify what user registry are you using. 3. You specified `maximo` in the tags without writing to what maximo product it is related. Check [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21645570), if it is related to maximo.

Comment: Leo did you solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the [following](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405302)?

To disable security, please perform the following steps via wsadmin:

1. /bin/> wsadmin -conntype NONE
2. wsadmin> securityoff
3. wsadmin> exit
4. Restart the servers.
5. Enable the security from administrative console.

Once the needed corrections are made, you can re-enable security in the admin console and then restart WebSphere.

NOTE: To restart the servers, you will first need to manually kill the java process since security is still enabled in the currently running process.

**Or editing the xml file**

Following [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21295051) you have 2 optiont:

This is for the **standalone version**

1. Make a backup of the security.xml file: 
   /config/cells/cellname/security.xml
2. Edit the security.xml file by searching for the first instance of " enabled= ". You should see enabled="true" as in:
3. Change to enabled="false".
4. Save the security.xml file.
5. Restart server1 and the WebSphere_Portal servers. If you get authentication exceptions while trying to stop the servers, you may have to manually kill the server processes and then restart them.
6. In the wpconfig.properties file, make the following changes: 
   PortalAdminId=wpsadmin 
   PortalAdminGroupId=wpsadmins

   Refer to the Information Center link for specific instructions.
7. Save the wpconfig.propeties file.
8. Try to disable security again using the disable-security task:

./WPSconfig.sh disable-securit y 
At this point, security should be disabled. You can verify by accessing the WebSphere Application Server admin console. You should be prompted for only a user name, not a password.

Follow these instructions for a **clustered version**:

1. Make a backup of the security.xml file on the Deployment Manager machine:
   /config/cells/cellname/security.xml
2. Edit the security.xml file by searching for the first instance of "enabled= ". You should see enabled="true" as in:
3. Change to enabled="false".
4. Save the security.xml file.
5. Copy the security.xml file to the nodes: 
   /config/cells/cellname/security.xml 
   /config/cells/cellname/security.xml
6. Restart DMGR, NodeAgents, and WebSphere_Portal servers. If you get authentication exceptions while trying to stop the servers, you may have to manually kill the server processes and then restart them.
7. In wpconfig.properties, make the following changes: 
   PortalAdminId=wpsadmin 
   PortalAdminGroupId=wpsadmins

Refer to the Information Center link for specific instructions.

8. Save the wpconfig.propeties file.
9. Try to disable security again using the disable-security task. Note that the DMGR and the nodeagent should be running: 
   ./WPSconfig.sh disable-security 
   At this point, security should be disabled. You can verify by accessing the DMGR AdminConsole. You should be prompted for only a user name, not a password.

---

Or more option is explained [here](http://notesbusters.com/2012/10/01/websphere-wasadmin-how-to-recover-a-lost-password/)
**Note:** I haven't tried this myself yet

Answer (score 1):

Goto DMGR bin directory and follow the below process.

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./wsadmin.sh -connType NONE -lang jython

wsadmin>AdminTask.changeFileRegistryAccountPassword('-userId saddam -password saddamm')
wsadmin>AdminConfig.save()
```

Please restart dmgr.

If you have forgotten the password, then you have to directly kill the dmgr process id and start dmgr.

Answer (score 0):

Login to WebSphere Console **->** Users and Groups **->** Manage Users **->** click on <**user_name**> **->** change the password value **->** save the configuration.